# Export as CSV accessing elements of an array and inserting line breaks

Tags: ruby-on-rails, csv, rubygems, export-to-csv

I have a document stored in Mongo inside the jobs collection that looks like this:

```
"products" : [  {   "id" : "51bc0cc39727911120000145",  "price" : 19,   "quantity" : 1,     "tax" : 0 },    {   "id" : "51bc0cc39727911120000171",  "price" : 14,   "quantity" : 1,     "tax" : 0 },    {   "id" : "51bc0cca9727911120000a23",  "price" : 308,  "quantity" : 1,     "tax" : 0.092500001192093 } ]
```

products is an array of arrays.  When you export as CSV, this entire line prints out when you access the "products" key (naturally).

What I need to do:

Reach inside products and grab EACH of the elements, printing them in appropriate columns in the CSV AND inserting a line break in the CSV such that they line up under the appropriate columns.

Something like:

ID  PRICE  QUANTITY  TAX
ID  PRICE  QUANTITY  TAX
ID  PRICE  QUANTITY  TAX

Line 1 above to the left has the actual JOB NUMBER, but lines 2 and 3 wouldn't have that (it would be redundant).

The crazy part is I need some each logic that will grab however many parts are added to the job (from none to infinity).

Does anyone have any idea how to pull this off?

I'm using the comma gem, so I have some code in my model:

products do |products|
  #I've tried untold combos here - none of which work
end

Help!

UPDATE:

Something like this gets the first element out of products (and payments which is structured the same)

```
products do |products|
      products.each do |p|
        @pid = p["id"]
        @pid = Inventory.find_by_id(@pid)
        if @pid == nil
          @pid = "None"
        else
          @pid = @pid.parts_name
        end
      end
      @pid
    end
    products 'Price' do |products|
      products.each do |p|
        @price = p["price"]
      end
      @price
    end
    products 'Quantity' do |products|
      products.each do |p|
        @qty = p["quantity"]
      end
      @qty
    end
    products 'Tax' do |products|
      products.each do |p|
        @tax = (p["tax"].to_f * (p["price"].to_f * p["quantity"].to_i)).round(2)
      end
      @tax
    end
```

Any idea on for loop logic ?

Comment: Looks like products is an array of Hashes!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is a snippit of the final solution:

```
products do |products|
      @prod=[]
      products.each do |p|
        @pid = p["id"]
        @pid = Inventory.find_by_id(@pid)
        if @pid == nil
          @prod << "None"
        else
          @prod << @pid.parts_name
        end
      end
      @prod.to_sentence(:words_connector=>"\r",:two_words_connector=>"\r",:last_word_connector=>"\r")
    end
```

The last part was one of those "screw it I'll try everything" approaches where I stumbled on an alternate use for the "to_sentence" method.  It works...

Answer (score 0):

maybe somethin like this would do

```
column_names = ["id","price","quantity","tax"] 
CSV.generate do |csv|
   csv << column_names
   products.each do |p|
     @pid = Inventory.find_by_id(p["id"])
     csv << [@pid ? @pid.parts_name : "none", p["price"], p["quantity"], (p["tax"].to_f * (p["price"].to_f * p["quantity"].to_i)).round(2) ]
   end
 end
```